# Nock not working for multiple tests running together

Tags: node.js, nock

I am using `nock` library to stub my http calls.
Different test files `require('nock')` and do their stubbing.
If each test is run separately, all is passing.
But if all tests run together, later tests fail **because instead of nock, actual request was made**.

> Consider below code snippet for example. It has two different `describe` blocks, each with multiple test cases. If I run this file `node node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha test.js` then the first two tests will pass, but the third test (in different `describe` block) would fail because it would actually call the `google` URL.

```
/* eslint-env mocha */

let expect = require('chai').expect
let nock = require('nock')
let request = require('request')

let url = 'http://localhost:7295'

describe('Test A', function () {
  after(function () {
    nock.restore()
    nock.cleanAll()
  })

  it('test 1', function (done) {
    nock(url)
      .post('/path1')
      .reply(200, 'input_stream1')

    request.post(url + '/path1', function (error, response, body) {
      expect(body).to.equal('input_stream1')
      done()
    })
  })

  it('test 2', function (done) {
    nock(url)
      .post('/path2')
      .reply(200, 'input_stream2')

    request.post(url + '/path2', function (error, response, body) {
      expect(body).to.equal('input_stream2')
      done()
    })
  })
})

// TESTS IN THIS BLOCK WOULD FAIL!!!
describe('Test B', function () {
  after(function () {
    nock.restore()
    nock.cleanAll()
  })

  it('test 3', function (done) {
    nock('http://google.com')
      .post('/path3')
      .reply(200, 'input_stream3')

    request.post('http://google.com' + '/path3', function (error, response, body) {
      expect(body).to.equal('input_stream3')
      done()
    })
  })
})
```

Funny thing is, if I do `console.log(nock.activeMocks())`, then I can see that nock did register the URL to mock.

```
[ 'POST http://google.com:80/path3' ]
```

Answer (score 5):

As discussed in this [Github Issue](https://github.com/node-nock/nock/issues/997), `nock.restore()` removes the http interceptor itself. When you run `nock.isActive()` after calling `nock.restore()` it will return `false`. So you need to run `nock.activate()` before using it again.

### Solution 1:

Remove `nock.restore()`.

### Solution 2:

Have this `before()` method in your test.

```
  before(function (done) {
    if (!nock.isActive()) nock.activate()
    done()
  })
```

Comment: thanks! you saved me a few minutes tracking that down in the docs!

Comment: Can you explain what your problem was, and if there was any error message?

Comment: my `before` is async thats why i  can not use done(). I put nock.cleanAll() inside `afterEach`

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by before is async...if possible why don't you post another question and send me the link...I will try to answer that.

Comment: i am using dotenv package in another file.I think dotenv is causing not to mock url using nock.If i remove dotenv then it works but if i keep dotenv it requests the original url from env. :(

Comment: I tried something similar, but can't seem to get the test to be passing. Could you please have a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59202099/testing-the-same-url-with-nock-mocha-and-lolex